# convert distinct key into columns in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i want to convert a key value RDD into columns where distinct key should be the column, for example

my RDD is something like this:-

```
(serviceName,service1)
(startTime,1234)
(endTime,2345)
(serviceName,service2)
(startTime,4567)
(endTime,7891)
```

result shoud be like

```
serviceName|startTime|endTime
-----------|---------|---------
service1   |1234     |2345
service2   |4567     |7891
```

can any one help achieving this in spark using scala.

Comment: How do you know 1234 belongs to service1, I guess they are not ordered in RDD?

Comment: Are you reading this from a file? if yes, how does the file look like?

Comment: Do `(serviceName,service1)` and `(serviceName,service2)` represent headers (column names)? meaning, you're talking about 2 RDDs here?

Or are they just rows in your RDD?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your RDD is something like RDD[(K, V)]. Also assume that you read from a file so your RDD will always be ordered like that. You can take rows periodically with the following code:

`rdd.zipWithIndex.filter(_._2==0).map(_._1._2) // then replace 0 with 1, 2`

The output will be 3 RDDs with no keys (the name of the column), but you can find them using:

`rdd.zipWithIndex.filter(_._2==0).map(_._1._1).first() // then replace 0 with 1, 2`